# Defining img custom property

Tags: javascript, dom, opera, mozilla

I'm trying to assign property "itemId" for DOM element "img"

Here is code

```
var img = document.createElement('IMG');
window.console.log(itemId);
img.itemId = itemId;
window.console.log(img.itemId);
```

After execution console contains this messages:

```
41
http://example.domain/41
```

Where example.domain - is adress of my site.

This problem appears in Opera and Mozilla, but in Chrome this code works fine (img.itemId == 41). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uwPY5/

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Thanks to @Rodik - your answers helpt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very weird behavior, but try the standard way:

```
img.setAttribute("itemId", itemId);
```

To be compatible with HTML5 though, you should prefix your attribute name like this:

```
img.setAttribute("data-itemId", itemId);
```

Then to read it back:

```
var itemId = img.getAttribute("data-itemId");
```

Comment: Moreover, you should always prefix custom attributes like this: `data-itemId`

Comment: @Rodik why? Where is it written? I saw it first used only in jQuery.

Comment: `A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no characters in the range U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z).`
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#custom-data-attribute

Comment: It is written in the HTML5 specification document.

Comment: @Rodik Thanks, wasn't aware of that (one never stop learning!) edited my post to reflect this, but still using the old fashion `setAttribute` to support older browsers.

Comment: @mikle you must read is using `getAttribute()` see [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwPY5/4/) which also work in Firefox.